# Why $\lim_{h\to 0}\sup_{u\in[0,1]}|f(x+hu)-f(x)|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and $x\in]a,b[$. Let $h$ such that $x+h\in]a,b[$. Why do we have that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\sup_{u\in[0,1]}|f(x+hu)-f(x)|=0.$$

I would say that since $f$ is continuous, for all $u\in[0,1]$ $$\lim_{h\to 0 }|f(x+uh)-f(x)|=0$$ and thus $$\lim_{h\to 0}\sup_{u\in[0,1]}|f(x+hu)-f(x)|=0.$$

I'm not sure if my argument is correct.

Comment: I don't think this is enough since $\sup_{u\in [0,1]}|f(x+uh)-f(x)|\ge |f(x+uh)-f(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $[a,b]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. Therefore given $\varepsilon>0$, we may choose $\delta>0$ such that $|y-z|<\delta$ implies $|f(y)-f(z)|<\varepsilon$ for all $y,z\in[a,b]$. So for $h<\delta$, we have $$|(x+hu)-x|=|hu|\leqslant h$$
for all $u\in[0,1]$. Hence
$$\lim_{h\to0}\sup_{u\in[0,1]}|f(x+hu)-f(x)|<\varepsilon, $$
from which the claim follows.